# Unexpected Solr scores for documents boosted by the same boost values

Tags: sorting, solr, lucene, sunspot

I have 2 documents:

```
{
    title: "Popular",
    registrations_count: 700,
    is_featured: false
}
```

and

```
{
    title: "Unpopular",
    registrations_count: 100,
    is_featured: true
}
```

I'm running this Solr query (via the Ruby Sunspot gem):

```
fq: ["type:Event"],
sort: "score desc",
q: "*:*",
defType: "edismax",
fl: "* score",
bq: ["registrations_count_i:[700 TO *]^10", "is_featured_bs:true^10"],
start: 0, rows: 30
```

or, for those who are more used to ruby:

```
Challenge.search do    
    boost(10) do
       with(:registrations_count).greater_than_or_equal_to(700)
    end

    boost(10) do
        with(:is_featured, true)
    end

    order_by :score, :desc
end
```

One document matches the first boost query, and the other matches the other boost query. They have the same boost value.

What I would expect is that both documents get the same score. But they don't, they get something like that

```
1.2011336 # score for 'unpopular' (featured)
0.6366436 # score for 'popular' (not featured)
```

I also checked that if i boost an attribute that they both have in common, they get the exact same score, and they do. I also tried to change the `700` value, to something like `7000`, but it makes no difference (which makes total sense).

**Can anyone explain why they get such a different score, while they both match one of the boost queries?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the confusion stems from "the queries being boosted by the same value" - that's not true - the boost is the *score of the query itself*, which is then amplified 10x by your `^10`.

The `bq` is additive - the score from the query is added to the score of the document (while `boost` is multiplicative, the score is multiplied by the boost query).

If you instead want to add the same score value to the original query based on either one matching, you can use `^=10` which makes the query constant scoring (the score will be `10` for that term, regardless of the regular score of the document).

Also, if you want to apply these factors independent of each other (instead of as a single, merged score with contributions from both factors), use multiple `bq` entries instead.

Comment: Yep, that's definitely something I had not understood about how boosting worked. Thanks!

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know when `^=` was added to solr? I'm using an outdated solr 4.x  version, and if I'm not doing something wrong, it doesnt seem to be supported.

Comment: I just saw someone mention Solr 5.1. Not sure if it's the first release that does, but it's likely that 4.0 doesn't.

Comment: That's correct. 4.0 is too old to support most modern features in Solr (since it's about 8-9 years old now). You might be able to use a boost function instead with a few if-s, but I do not remember which parts are supported by 4.0 and which aren't.

Comment: Constant scoring operator was added in Solr 5.1 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-7218

Comment: Thanks guys. I was able to use a dirty trick to make it work, but I'll try to upgrade soon. Basically, I read somewhere that range queries have constant score, so using `"is_featured_bs:[true TO true]^10"` technically works and gives me exactly the amount of boost expected. Not too happy about that solution tho.